# Block input type radio in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

everyone. I have a problem that arises after changing excluding params. I use Redux to save all params data but I have an incomprehensible error. I add a video that shows that problem. Also, I attach some code parts. All elements are memo. Events are disabled after second param change. [video](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/moJX6CEzVZdpdg)

```js
if (value === "true" || value === "false") {
      newValue = value === "true" ? true : false;
    }
 
if (newValue === true && (name === "DU_DT" || name === "SINF")) {
      if (name === "DU_DT") {
        result = { ...values, DU_DT: true, SINF: false };
      } else {
        result = { ...values, DU_DT: false, SINF: true };
      }
    } else {
      result = { ...values, [name]: newValue }
    }
 
    dispatch({
      type: ConfigurationActions.SET_VALUES,
      payload: result,
    });
```